# Gmail's confirmation verification never arrives

Tags: gmail, account-management, notifications, email-forwarding

I've seen questions about this dating back to 2009 - but not a single answer. When I add a new email to my Gmail account, I can send and receive from/to that email through my Gmail account no problem.

But, I can't add it as a "sent from" until I get the verification code from Google.

The only thing is, no matter how many times I've sent and resent this confirmation email, it does not arrive.

Yes, I checked my spam, trash, and all filters.

No, it is not hosted by someone else. It is a forward.

Yes, I have other addresses from the same place that work just fine.

Yes, I can send emails to (and receive them from) this account, through my Gmail account, no problem.

The issue is with Gmail's verification.

Please, from the experiences I've seen here, I know Google will not answer. Does anyone have a way to glean the code that does not involve this non-existent email?

Comment: "I can send and receive from/to that email through my Gmail account" - Presumably you can't "send from that email through [your] Gmail account", which I assume in your problem. Presumably you have a suitable SMTP server setup through which to send email? (Google turned off its own SMTP server a short while ago.)

Comment: The "other addresses" for which you did receive the verification email are on the _same domain_?

Comment: I have an smtp server, separate from Google. I have entered that information, as instructed. I even went to gmail and sent an email to that address. Got it. Sent an email from that address to my gmail account. Got it. Host is working.

DELETED and RE-ADDED address, includng smtp, password, etc. Resent gmail verification twice. Still nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Try to

1. have the email address first forward to a non-Gmail provider (like protonmail)
2. send and use the Gmail verification code/link received at this provider
3. change forwarding to Gmail account
4. test if Gmail can receive

Ridiculous, I know.

Answer (score -2):

Finally have the answer after having the same problem myself for months. The Gmail inbox is divided into primary and social. The Facebook message will be in the social division. Hope that works.